# Is there a cipher that uses part of the already-computed ciphertext in the encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, modes-of-operation, terminology

Are there any famous ciphers that, to determine the encrypted letter at position n in the ciphertext, it uses the encrypted letter at position n-1 in the ciphertext?

I tried google but I couldn't figure out how to phrase my search terms correctly to find something like this.

Comment: Would CBC mode count?

Comment: For classic (pre-electronic) ciphers this was not uncommon and was mostly called 'autokey' (auto being Greek for self)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autokey_cipher

Answer (score 3):

The concept you mentioned is used in self synchronising stream ciphers. For example, CFB mode of a block cipher uses
$$C_0=IV$$
$$C_n=E_K(C_{n-1})\oplus P_n, \quad n \geq 1$$
with $C_n,P_n$ denoting the $n^{th}$ plaintext and ciphertext blocks.
So if you substitute "block" for "symbol", this is the same as what you want. CBC mode also gives a self synchronising stream cipher.

Moustique is a self synchronising stream cipher designed by J Daemen.

Answer (score 3):

If we can extend "letter" to "block", then [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) is quite an obvious answer. It chains the blocks together so that each plaintext block is XOR'ed with the previous ciphertext block before encryption, i.e. $C_{n} = E_k(P_{n} \oplus C_{n-1}) $.